# Installing cabot via vagrant or docker

Tags: vagrant, monitoring, docker

Trying to install cabot, but am having no luck.
Any help would be grateful

Via vagrant(http://cabotapp.com/dev/get-started.html) I get the following

[image]

I have also tried to install via docker (https://github.com/shoonoise/cabot-docker) and had no luck

Anyone have this up and running?